# JBOSS 7 doesnt start up

Tags: jboss

My jboss server doesn't start up, whenever someone changes code, we notify in jenkins and we hit build, after that when i SSH in to the instance, I can see that jboss doesn't startup automatically, every time I have to start up manually,

any help please with the command?

The First picture we have to stop the jBOSS , I have used the sudo service jbossas7 stop command, didn't work either again in the second pic, I have started the JBOSS, but still doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The command in line 3 of your script kills all jboss instances. ;)

Hence you must start a new instance, for example with

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh &
```

Comment: well, I need to kill the process to start deplying some war files , But any how i am issuing a command to start up the JBOSS at the end of the script if you observe